# Building docker image fails with failed to fetch anonymous token, TLS handshake timeout

Tags: docker

I got a problem while creating a docker image using `docker build -t image_name .`. When I execute it I get errors:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8                                                    0.2s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fjava%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Comment: As a workaround I've done `docker pull` for base image before `docker build`.

Comment: is the question still relevant? and if so, what OS are you using? how did you install docker? what pulling the image manually returns?

Comment: @SerG - Thanks!

Comment: Was getting a similar error in using docker-compose build with Mercury ( which serves Jupyter notebooks via Docker: https://github.com/mljar/mercury ).  Solution in my case was to delete a bare-string multiline comment from the notebook.  (Expected notebook format didn't allow a string at that spot.) TL;DR: This can also be due to bugs in the individual containers, rather than host DNS.

Comment: Thanks @SerG I wish I had landed on your comment 2 hours ago, somehow pulling the image again has allowed me to build...

Answer (score 22):

This recently happened for me when running a build script for [earthly/earthly](https://github.com/earthly/earthly).

OS: Arch Linux `5.14.8-arch1-1`

Docker from official repository: `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d28e`

##### Solution (likely a Linux-only solution)

DNS was misconfigured for me. For some reason, `docker pull golang:1.16-alpine3.14` worked fine but was failing when running the build script. [This answer on r/docker](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/e5h4cy/comment/f9jslef) helped.

Adding a DNS nameserver to my `/etc/resolv.conf` solved this issue for me:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Cloudflare
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

##### Other Attempted Solutions

**1. Disable Buildkit**

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65362210/4676641) to [Docker build: failed to fetch oauth token for openjdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361083/docker-build-failed-to-fetch-oauth-token-for-openjdk), this did not solve the issue since I believe buildkit was required for the script I was running:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

**2. Manually pull image**

**3. Authenticating with Docker**

The error looked like something that might happen when I was unauthenticated with hub.docker.com. After logging in with `docker login --username <username>` I still receieved the errors.

Comment: On my machine, I have a `/etc/resolv.conf` but no `/etc/resolve.conf`, notice the extra `e`. Not sure if this file's name varies with distribution.

Comment: @PatrikIselind You're right and I misspelled the filename. Edited to fix, thanks! https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html

Comment: manually pulling the image helped me. it was exactly timing out at 20 seconds every time

Comment: @tentative you only edited it in one location.

Comment: This solved the problem for me but I spent a couple of hours longer than I needed because of that extra e. For me it was an issue because the machine has 2 network cards. I tried editing your post myself but it said "edit queue is full". Edit -> Oh, you fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to login. Thanks for saving me couple of hours XD

Answer (score 4):

If you use MacOS check if there are any kind of System Extensions which intercept the traffic - e.g. firewalls, vpn clients, security tools.
run `systemextensionsctl list` in your terminal app:

```
1 extension(s)
--- com.apple.system_extension.network_extension
enabled active  teamID  bundleID (version)  name    [state]
*   *   78UFGP42EU  ch.tripmode.TripMode.FilterExtension (3.1.0/1304)   FilterExtension [activated enabled]
```

In my case the App [**TripMode**](https://tripmode.ch) was the reason for the problem. Uninstalling the tool and restarting the system fixed the problem.

Comment: It was the VPN...

Answer (score 3):

In my case this happened on Ubuntu WSL2 for Windows. This happened while running

`docker build -t cbusha-be:latest .`

On accident after having already ran

`docker buildx build -t cbusha-be:latest .`

once I switched back to the BuildX command it worked again

Answer (score 1):

Check manually if you can `docker pull` same emage with version on the server. Maybe the image has been deleted from registry.
You can also find image you want to pull and use copy&paste command eg from https://hub.docker.com/_/node/tags to be sure that there is no typo

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on to answer regarding setting DNS in resolv.conf, but I don't have enough reputation to comment apparently.  Some Linux applications read resolv.conf directly and do not use systemd-resolved (which is used by Arch by default).  You can address this by replacing /etc/resolv.conf with a link to a systemd-resolved DNS stub file like
`ln -rsf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

It is covered in the DNS section of this documentation https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved