# sail fails to build docker image

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, wsl-2, laravel-sail

There are not too many solutions, I tried to implement what I found so far:
I have a sail project placed into my wsl.
The iisue I'm facing is that when running sail up, the laravel building section fails with the following error:

```
failed to solve: ubuntu:22.04: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get 
"https://auth.docker.io/token? 
scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fubuntu%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp: lookup 
auth.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:34022->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

What tried so far:

- disable buildkit in the docker file
- login to docker using command line
- add dns values to daemon.json, altghough when I run `docker run busybox nslookup google.com`, it works fine.

Running out of ideas. I have a feeling I will end up wit re-installing my wsl.

Comment: I literally searched `failed to solve: ubuntu:22.04: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token` on google, and this is the first link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69432587/1998801

Comment: I saw that. You can see that  I tried the suggestions given there. I cannot pull it manually because the whole network is handled by sail. That post is not even solved.