# error: failed to solve: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp: i/o timeout

Tags: java, linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image for my java file on my M1 max MacBook, my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
COPY . /src/java
WORKDIR /src/java
RUN ["javac","greenchallenge.java"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","greenchallenge"]
```

Steps followed to build the image:

1. Created a new builder using: `docker buildx create --name pibuilder`
   (*I wanted to use the multi architecture feature*)
2. Initialed the builder using: `docker buildx use pibuilder` .
3. Built the image and pushed it using:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t my_java:latest -t my_java:1.0.0 --push .
```

After running **step-3**, I got the below log:

```
[+] Building 47.2s (7/7) FINISHED                                               
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                           15.8s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                        15.2s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_javabuildernew40                 0.6s
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 351B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => ERROR [linux/arm/v7 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/op  31.3s
 => CANCELED [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/  31.3s
 => CANCELED [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/  31.3s
 => [auth] library/openjdk:pull token for registry-1.docker.io             0.0s
------
 > [linux/arm/v7 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8-alpine:
------
dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM openjdk:8-alpine
   2 |     COPY . /src/java
   3 |     WORKDIR /src/java
--------------------
error: failed to solve: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

**Note:** I'm using work Environment, I bypassed proxy as well.
**Note:** As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361083/docker-build-failed-to-fetch-oauth-token-for-openjdk) I set `"buildkit":false` and used `docker login` in terminal.

Hope you help me to solve the error, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `buildkit` option to `false` is not sufficient, if you are behind a proxy, you should set **both** `HTTP_PROXY`and HTTPS_PROXY` env vars to get it work.

on Windows, in a CMD :

```
set HTTP_PROXY=YourProxyUrl:Port
set HTTPS_PROXY=YourProxyUrl:Port
```

on Windows in a GitBash shell, or on a MacOs shell :

```
export HTTP_PROXY=YourProxyUrl:Port
export HTTPS_PROXY=YourProxyUrl:Port
```