# Docker build shows an error with load metadata

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am using Docker on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. When I am trying to build a docker image it shows an error like

```
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:trusty
=> [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
-------
>[internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:trusty:
----------------------
Dockerfile:1
----------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: ubuntu:trusty: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: post "https://auth.docker.io/token" : dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53 read udp 192.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx->127.0.0.53.53: i/o timeout
```

Until yesterday the build was working fine. But suddenly this error comes today and the build is not happening.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker build: failed to fetch oauth token for openjdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361083/docker-build-failed-to-fetch-oauth-token-for-openjdk)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some download layer is corrupt.

Try cleaning up your environment by `docker system prune --all` the try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the Docker daemon?

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Restart the docker daemon and try again.